# Why Bulk update operation is not working if i passes _id in matching condition using Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am facing a problem while using bulk update operation in mongoose. Whenever i passes _id in matching condition. it will not updated the result and when i changed my condition criteria besides _id, It works fine. Any idea about that. Please help me. Here is my code

```
     var bulk = roleObj.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
     bulk.find({_id: '56b9ba46b51a3b2114b0b44e'}).update({$set: {name: 'bla bla'}});
     bulk.execute(function (err, data) {
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are calling the underlying mongo collection's bulk methods, not the mongoose API methods which automatically wrap the string `_id`s for you in **[`ObjectID`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)**. You need to cast the string to **[`ObjectID`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)** first then use it in your bulk update:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('56b9ba46b51a3b2114b0b44e');
    bulk = roleObj.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find({_id: id}).update({$set: {name: 'bla bla'}});
bulk.execute(function (err, data) { ... });
```